# How to center background image in QWidget

Tags: python, qtableview, pyside2

The code below creates a singe QTableView with the jpg image set as background.

I would like this background image to be centered instead of aligned with the left and top edges. How to position the background image at the center?

```
from PySide2.QtGui import *
from PySide2.QtWidgets import *
from PySide2.QtCore import *

app = QApplication([])
view = QTableView()
view.resize(1000, 600)
bg_image = 'stackoverflow.jpg'
view.setStyleSheet("background-repeat:no-repeat;background-image:url(%s)" % bg_image)
view.show()
app.exec_()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the `background-position` property to `center`:

```
view.setStyleSheet(
    """
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    background-image: url(%s);
    """
    % bg_image
)
```